# MalformedJsonException: JSON at line 2 column 2

Tags: json, malformed

So, i am having the problem named by the title. However, i cannot find what is wrong with it. Below is the JSON config:

```
{
    "0.6": {
        "platforms": {
            "win32": {
                "cef.pak": "35e7111a7d6fdd81cb6fcfc87497600cdab7456b",
                "cef_100_percent.pak": "2ee3e69b1ff8aa82ef4cae62975aac4d90290222",
                "cef_200_percent.pak": "69b1d9f37b52159904c843f031d1e50c3ab0ab1c",
                "d3dcompiler_43.dll": "98be17e1d324790a5b206e1ea1cc4e64fbe21240",
                "d3dcompiler_46.dll": "9dcd5b3a05b4fd1c71198fc11aa0f8f569a3e21d",
                "devtools_resources.pak": "842499621764622b33a2bcd55fc131925f98f310",
                "ffmpegsumo.dll": "53b4650870481c5b98e0e5a9e10164298597eb5a",
                "icudtl.dat": "1ecbe1bd741c7101c72361d1d3dab5ad9056c2a1",
                "jcef.dll": "df7e928433c2adae617c7f0042c9c19a525262f5",
                "jcef_helper.exe": "eff10c426131809ff676b8826a87dd2f5e82b028",
                "libcef.dll": "4edf7494c42c4eaa69e9bafa70badef117579b2d",
                "libEGL.dll": "d0385658e88dca2df63b1aa39fe6506ccc93e791",
                "libGLESv2.dll": "45da37ad25345fadad8d9228fda9bed1d24fcb03",
                "locales.zip": "fbe947b00b558949cda51462430bfdff1d30547e",
                "pdf.dll": "ff19418182dad96cd43e485f488010855196c6be"
            },

            "win64": {
                "cef.pak": "35e7111a7d6fdd81cb6fcfc87497600cdab7456b",
                "cef_100_percent.pak": "2ee3e69b1ff8aa82ef4cae62975aac4d90290222",
                "cef_200_percent.pak": "69b1d9f37b52159904c843f031d1e50c3ab0ab1c",
                "d3dcompiler_43.dll": "98be17e1d324790a5b206e1ea1cc4e64fbe21240",
                "d3dcompiler_46.dll": "9ced490f112005df9576d16ee06d8004db44afbe",
                "devtools_resources.pak": "842499621764622b33a2bcd55fc131925f98f310",
                "ffmpegsumo.dll": "19a5e8a58c2a26a1a4039614caf10b06421a3b00",
                "icudtl.dat": "1ecbe1bd741c7101c72361d1d3dab5ad9056c2a1",
                "jcef.dll": "eb2196dbaee4fc88bbe78ca1d2b2671d57795111",
                "jcef_helper.exe": "d96ad53efa97d8357c5f2ddda47a4d396f8f8076",
                "libcef.dll": "d1ea4e67de9572e65cea04eaec809ff1dce9d9e0",
                "libEGL.dll": "505cf7e18d0fea964b0cc80aeef4a69701dc2a80",
                "libGLESv2.dll": "ff159e7940bbfed3e9d80771dafba0449ffdd7f7",
                "pdf.dll": "69ca1429ade0be98ec253c5f58b76a8943b0dad4",
                "locales.zip": "d541cbec7113ec14d3a7f79b10be67e27ac37cee"
            },

            "linux64": {
                "cef_100_percent.pak": "a442628aefa628aef1ee35a071b7f9c45db617cd",
                "cef_200_percent.pak": "0a7a66cf596567d57833e57eaeae2f5904ec9201",
                "cef.pak": "7804c134a0ac52caf3cec28a7eae75547a03125d",
                "chrome-sandbox": "90c083edf9ac6e9037db59691f5844f217794621",
                "devtools_resources.pak": "4f49df1670e648dfd7c1236c1e0a559fa06fa081",
                "icudtl.dat": "22c8b378d1695e0f94ae8d52c9480eccff92f62c",
                "jcef_helper": "5a95eb493125c3f7bf797e673129a2b513d8f528",
                "libcef.so": "94c6d5cccf3158f5db8bcf2d746b7083f699e84a",
                "libjcef.so": "960521a1d8ced95612da2573a338ae97596f8835",
                "locales.zip": "3c879f079c19ef743174ef7f48f0acde7573698c",
                "natives_blob.bin": "d04538ee75d54587472ef1bbfe343b087e40d5fd",
                "snapshot_blob.bin": "b2ce2dfebad637ca9402f9f206beb49c3af902e2"
            }
        },

        "extract": [ "locales.zip" ]
    },

    "0.7": {
        "platforms": {
            "win32": {
                "cef.pak": "35e7111a7d6fdd81cb6fcfc87497600cdab7456b",
                "cef_100_percent.pak": "2ee3e69b1ff8aa82ef4cae62975aac4d90290222",
                "cef_200_percent.pak": "69b1d9f37b52159904c843f031d1e50c3ab0ab1c",
                "d3dcompiler_43.dll": "98be17e1d324790a5b206e1ea1cc4e64fbe21240",
                "d3dcompiler_46.dll": "9dcd5b3a05b4fd1c71198fc11aa0f8f569a3e21d",
                "devtools_resources.pak": "842499621764622b33a2bcd55fc131925f98f310",
                "ffmpegsumo.dll": "53b4650870481c5b98e0e5a9e10164298597eb5a",
                "icudtl.dat": "1ecbe1bd741c7101c72361d1d3dab5ad9056c2a1",
                "jcef.dll": "df7e928433c2adae617c7f0042c9c19a525262f5",
                "jcef_helper.exe": "eff10c426131809ff676b8826a87dd2f5e82b028",
                "libcef.dll": "4edf7494c42c4eaa69e9bafa70badef117579b2d",
                "libEGL.dll": "d0385658e88dca2df63b1aa39fe6506ccc93e791",
                "libGLESv2.dll": "45da37ad25345fadad8d9228fda9bed1d24fcb03",
                "locales.zip": "fbe947b00b558949cda51462430bfdff1d30547e",
                "pdf.dll": "ff19418182dad96cd43e485f488010855196c6be"
            },

            "win64": {
                "cef.pak": "35e7111a7d6fdd81cb6fcfc87497600cdab7456b",
                "cef_100_percent.pak": "2ee3e69b1ff8aa82ef4cae62975aac4d90290222",
                "cef_200_percent.pak": "69b1d9f37b52159904c843f031d1e50c3ab0ab1c",
                "d3dcompiler_43.dll": "98be17e1d324790a5b206e1ea1cc4e64fbe21240",
                "d3dcompiler_46.dll": "9ced490f112005df9576d16ee06d8004db44afbe",
                "devtools_resources.pak": "842499621764622b33a2bcd55fc131925f98f310",
                "ffmpegsumo.dll": "19a5e8a58c2a26a1a4039614caf10b06421a3b00",
                "icudtl.dat": "1ecbe1bd741c7101c72361d1d3dab5ad9056c2a1",
                "jcef.dll": "eb2196dbaee4fc88bbe78ca1d2b2671d57795111",
                "jcef_helper.exe": "d96ad53efa97d8357c5f2ddda47a4d396f8f8076",
                "libcef.dll": "d1ea4e67de9572e65cea04eaec809ff1dce9d9e0",
                "libEGL.dll": "505cf7e18d0fea964b0cc80aeef4a69701dc2a80",
                "libGLESv2.dll": "ff159e7940bbfed3e9d80771dafba0449ffdd7f7",
                "pdf.dll": "69ca1429ade0be98ec253c5f58b76a8943b0dad4",
                "locales.zip": "d541cbec7113ec14d3a7f79b10be67e27ac37cee"
            },

            "linux64": {
                "cef_100_percent.pak": "a442628aefa628aef1ee35a071b7f9c45db617cd",
                "cef_200_percent.pak": "0a7a66cf596567d57833e57eaeae2f5904ec9201",
                "cef.pak": "7804c134a0ac52caf3cec28a7eae75547a03125d",
                "chrome-sandbox": "90c083edf9ac6e9037db59691f5844f217794621",
                "devtools_resources.pak": "4f49df1670e648dfd7c1236c1e0a559fa06fa081",
                "icudtl.dat": "22c8b378d1695e0f94ae8d52c9480eccff92f62c",
                "jcef_helper": "5a95eb493125c3f7bf797e673129a2b513d8f528",
                "libcef.so": "94c6d5cccf3158f5db8bcf2d746b7083f699e84a",
                "libjcef.so": "960521a1d8ced95612da2573a338ae97596f8835",
                "locales.zip": "3c879f079c19ef743174ef7f48f0acde7573698c",
                "natives_blob.bin": "d04538ee75d54587472ef1bbfe343b087e40d5fd",
                "snapshot_blob.bin": "b2ce2dfebad637ca9402f9f206beb49c3af902e2"
            }
        },

        "extract": [ "locales.zip" ]
    },

    "latestVersions": {
        "1.8": "0.7",
        "1.7.10": "0.7"
    }
}
```

More info:

> [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:-1]:
>   com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use
>   JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column
>   2 [14:43:15] [Client thread/INFO] [STDERR/MCEF]:
>   [java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream:println:-1]:     at
>   com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:65)

Comment: That JSON is valid. Can you provide the code that reads and parses it that is throwing this exception?

Comment: I think its this one: https://github.com/montoyo/mcef/blob/master/java/net/montoyo/mcef/remote/RemoteConfig.java

Comment: You see, the problem is, that this all worked some days ago. The java code cannot be updated remotely, so it has to be something with this config. We are using v0.6 of the mod, and MCEF downloads configs from the Internet, or better said, this website: https://montoyo.net/jcef/

Comment: By that, only the config could have been messed with, since the mod has been the same all the time, sitting at our clients. The only thing updated at every start, is the libraries required for MCEF to run, and it fetches these updates from the link i posted.